# Instantiation of InternetAddress cause NPE although check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jakarta-mail

Guys I originally thought that Java was ignoring my check for a null value, after careful inspection and debugging here's the silly code which is part of a huge program. I cannot post the entire method but this should get the point across.

```
public class NullCheck {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String>copied = new ArrayList<String>();
    copied.add("bg@ascii.com");
    copied.add(null);

    /* Built MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); */
    InternetAddress[] copiedPeople = new InternetAddress[copied.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < copied.size(); i++)
    {
        String recCC = (String)copied.get(i);
        if ((recCC != null) && (!recCC.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
            try {
                copiedPeople[i] = new InternetAddress((String)copied.get(i));
            } catch (AddressException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
            // I crash here
//  msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, copiedPeople);
}
}
```

I know this code is fine because it runs no problem for say the 1st 14 iterations. Again I thought my null check was being ignored but it is not! When the InternetAddress array get instantiated it get set to [null,null] so the for loop properly ignores the second item in ArrayList but when the loop finished the call to addRecepients, the ArrayList still has the 2nd null from instantiation!! How could I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different algorithm.  It looks like addRecipients requires none of the recipients to be null.  In that case, you need to pass it an array of exactly the right length.  The easiest way would be to remove all the null elements from copied, then pass copied.toArray() as the second parameter.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < copied.size())
{
        String recCC = (String)copied.get(i);
        if ((recCC == null){
            copied.remove(i);
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
}
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, copied.toArray());
```

If you can't alter the copied ArrayList, then you can create a new array list first, not add the nulls into it, then use toArray on the version without nulls.